# Best way to get man to open in emacs by default

Tags: shell, terminal-emacs, eshell, shell-command, keystrokes

I currently have:

```
man () { emacs -nw --eval "(man \"$1\")"; }
```

in my `.zshrc`. However, this has the problem of not working with something like `read(2)` or command-line arguments to man. The same problem exists in `eshell` for something like `read(2)` not working. However, `M-x man RET read(2) RET` works. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the point of this? If you want the man page, just run `man` on the command line. If you want emacs, just open emacs. In any case, I doubt this is emacs-related: it looks more like a quoting problem in zsh and so more appropriate for Unix & Linux SE perhaps.

Comment: I want the `man` page to display within emacs if I run man from the command-line.

Comment: Then at least, run a server and use `emacsclient` for that: starting a full session of Emacs just to display a manual page is rather wasteful.

Comment: You're probably right, and I'm considering switching to `emacsclient` but don't really see the purpose for me since it takes imperceivable time for emacs to launch for me (literally instantly) and I configured my `eshell` so that `emacs` aliases for `find-file`. I don't know what else I'd need it for except performance, which I have.